# Accessing a dataframe with head inside a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am reading a few XLS files via

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r'pathtofolder'
files = os.listdir(path=path)

dataframes = {}

for file in files:
    filepath = path + '\\' + file
    if filepath[-3:] == 'xls':
        print(file)
        dataframes[file] = pd.read_excel(filepath)
```

For some reason however, I can't access the dataframes inside the dictionaries, as .head() doesn't seem to work:

```
for file, dataframe in dataframes.items():
    dataframe.head()
```

This code doesn't seem to do anything in Jupyter. However when I type() dataframe, I get a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, so head should be working, right?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I haven't used pandas and dataframes in python but my input - 'dataframe' is defined as a dictionary in your code. A dictionary is an unordered data type, then why should it have a head, plus is head() even meant for dictionaries or dataframes? I haven't used dataframes in Python, but coming from R head() returns the first few rows and columns of a dataframe/matrix. 
Please also do show some output or error you are getting.

Comment: I dont get an error. There is no output at all...

Comment: Can you do `print(dataframe.columns)`? It seems like your dataframes are empty.

Comment: Try append your several dataframe.head() to a list, and print the list.

Answer (score 1):

haven't worked with Python data frames before, but I don't think your for loop will give you any output in this way. It's just a running loop which ends when the last head is calculated. You can just use print() to see your output.

```
for file, dataframe in mydict.items():
    print(dataframe.head())
```

Or create a reusable list of dataframe.head() as shown below. You enter the list name anytime in the console to view it later. Pardon the code for creating a dictionary of dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets

iris = pd.DataFrame(datasets.load_iris().data)
digits = pd.DataFrame(datasets.load_digits().data)
diabetes = pd.DataFrame(datasets.load_diabetes().data)

dataframes={'a':iris,'b':digits,'c':diabetes} #create a dictionary of dataframes 

list_heads=[]   #create a list of dataframe head()
    for i in dataframes:    
        list_heads.append(dataframes[i].head())
    list_heads
```

Comment: I still don't get it though. Inside the for loop the dataframe should be accessible via the dataframe variable. If I print it, the content is shown, but not in the nice formatting that pandas provide. So in the moment that I call .head(), why is that doing nothing? In other words, what would be the best way to read in multiple files in a folder to seperate dataframes, so that after I can access them via name and make the same operations on them, like deleting empty rows. I got over 50 files, so reading all in separately is a bit cumbersome..

Comment: You can read in files into a dict as you have above. I have just made three dataframes to make a dictionary like yours because i don't have the files you have ( reproducible example). Your dict of dataframes will work the same in above program. Also, dataframe.head() command without using print will output nothing because you are calling it over 50 times, dataframe.head() is not just a call, it is an evaluation as well. Do you expect an interactive python session evaluate and output df's 1 by 1? You can use a dataframe by dict['key'] for any ops. Using a list of df is standard.